# When run any flutter command return just cursor

Tags: command-line, git, command-line-tool

I am new programmer trying to install flutter into windows 10. I am currently stuck. I have installed git and flutter as per instruction from flutter.io.
Also added path variable on my user and system environments. Problem is that when I  launch flutter console,CMD or powershell and run flutter command and enter, I just get empty line with blinking cursor and I can not type or anything.. Help please..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while installing flutter to my device. For me, the problem was because i had installed flutter into a directory that it didn't have administrative privileges to even though it was running in an admin account. So a folder such as "program files", "program(x86)" and other related folders require a program to have admin privileges to access it of which flutter does not provide. so the solution is to shift the flutter folder you installed in these protected folders into a more open folder such as "user". Then after, change the path in your environment variables to the new one. Hope this will help, try it.